# Visual Studio Code doesn't format

Tags: c++, text, format, visual-studio-2013, formatting

I want to format my code by pressing Ctrl+K and Ctrl+D.
But after that, the code is still the same. For example:

```
void func1()
{

}

void func2() {

}
```

These functions still look the same after formating.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your keys aren't mapped the way you think. Go to the Edit/Advanced menu and choose Format Document.

Comment: I did that too, still doesn't work at all.

Comment: What's the filename you're working on? Maybe Visual Studio doesn't believe it's a code file.

Comment: It's a .cpp file in a regular project.

Comment: Verify your settings under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ text formatting engine is fairly limited when compared to C# or VB.Net.  It is pretty much limited to fixing indentation and correcting tabs vs. spaces.  It makes no attempt to clean up which line braces appear on.  Hence you're doing nothing wrong here, this is just a limitation of the C++ formatting engine

**EDIT**

As @dalle pointed out Visual Studio 2013 does indeed support limited brace formatting in C++.  By default though the formatting is turned off.  You need to explicitly enable it for format document to begin formatting your braces.

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> New Lines
- Select "Move to a new line" under "Position of open braces for functions"

Once this is done format document will begin to correctly position the braces

Comment: @dalle really?  That's a pleasant surprise. Firing up 2013 to take a look at it

Comment: @dalle indeed it does but by default the feature is disabled.  You have to opt into the brace formatting.  Updated my answer to explain how to do this